# Choose image from gallery and camera through web view is not working in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android-intent, webview, upload, android-6.0-marshmallow

Here is my code. I am using WebView for registration purposes. In the registration process I have to upload an image from the device. I have finished the code for this and it is working properly in every Android version except Marshmallow. I have given all necessary permissions from the manifest.

The code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = WebViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
private static long back_pressed;
private WebView webView;
private WebSettings webSettings;
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        Uri[] results = null;

        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }

        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;

    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }

        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;

            }

            Uri result = null;

            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                    result = null;

                } else {

                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;

        }
    }

    return;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);


    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
    //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration otherwise activate software acceleration
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    //webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webView.loadUrl("http://wordpresstesting.in/parinaypahal/Website/basicInformation");
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    // If it wasn't the Back key or there's no web page history, bubble up to the default
    // system behavior (probably exit the activity)

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                .setTitle("Exit!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                finish();
                            }

                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();

    }

    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();

    } else {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert)
                .setTitle("Exit!")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close?")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {

                                finish();
                            }

                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
    }

}

public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // For Android 5.0
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

        File imageStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                , "AndroidExampleFolder");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(
                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");
        Log.d("File", "File: " + file);
        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                , new Parcelable[]{captureIntent});

        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

}

public class PQClient extends WebViewClient {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        // If url contains mailto link then open Mail Intent
        if (url.contains("mailto:")) {

            // Could be cleverer and use a regex
            //Open links in new browser
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));

            // Here we can open new activity

            return true;

        } else {

            // Stay within this webview and load url
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //Show loader on url load
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

        // Then show progress  Dialog
        // in standard case YourActivity.this
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(WebViewActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.hide();
        }
    }

    // Called when all page resources loaded
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ " +
                "document.getElementById('android-app').style.display='none';})()");

        try {
            // Close progressDialog
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will allow implementing file uploading in most versions including the marshmellow and its tested too. But doesnt allow uploading multiple files though.

If anyone has a solution for that please do suggest it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;

private static final int INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private Uri mCapturedImageURI = null;
private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mFilePathCallback;
private String mCameraPhotoPath;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        Uri[] results = null;
        // Check that the response is a good one
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data == null) {
                // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                }
            } else {
                String dataString = data.getDataString();
                if (dataString != null) {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                }
            }
        }
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
        mFilePathCallback = null;
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                return;
            }
            Uri result = null;
            try {
                if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                    result = null;
                } else {
                    // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                    result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
    return;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("url");

           mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });


    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }
                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");
            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }
            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");
            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });
            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }
        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    });


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
    String webUrl = mWebView.getUrl();

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        switch(keyCode){
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(mWebView.canGoBack()){
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url"))){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Press the X button.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    if((webUrl.contains("url")||(webUrl.contains("file:///android_asset/error_page.html")||webUrl.contains("url")))) {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                                .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                    }else {
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
                }else {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("title")
                            .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the app?")
                            .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("no", null).show();
                }
                return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: This is only working solution I tried for webview file upload.

Comment: When do you delete the image that was created in createImageFile()?

Comment: @airowe when you have uploaded the image you get a json response back when your handling the json response you can delete the created image from the same location where it was created

Comment: I don't know what's wrong on my phone but uploading through camera works only a few times. say 4 out of 10 times. can u help me?

Comment: Don't know why but my onShowFileChooser method not calling if i click on <input type="file"> in web page.

Comment: don't know why but my camera is open and click a picture but in onActivityResult() did not get resultCode=-1(Activity.Result_ok) and not getting data from camera.

Comment: everything is OK. Thanks.

Comment: This works but the camera doesn't open, also capture="user" or "enviornment" doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The example code on [this page](https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/10/17/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-webview-in-l) helped me achieve these results after searching for hours.

```
// Create Function for Image Picker

mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public boolean onShowFileChooser(
        WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
        WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {

    // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
    if(mFilePathCallback != null) {
        mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
    }
    mFilePathCallback = filePathCallback;

    // Set up the take picture intent
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        } else {
            takePictureIntent = null;
        }
    }

    // Set up the intent to get an existing image
    Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

    // Set up the intents for the Intent chooser
    Intent[] intentArray;
    if(takePictureIntent != null) {
        intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
    } else {
        intentArray = new Intent[0];
    }

    Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

    return true;
}
});

// Return Data to Web Page

@Override
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        return;
    }

    Uri[] results = null;

    // Check that the response is a good one
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if(data == null) {
            // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
            if(mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
            }
        } else {
            String dataString = data.getDataString();
            if (dataString != null) {
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
            }
        }
    }

    mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
    mFilePathCallback = null;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below will let you selecting multiple images/files

At onActivityResult include the following code:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if (null != data.getClipData()) {
        final int numSelectedFiles = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
        results = new Uri[numSelectedFiles];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
            results[i] = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
        }
    }
}
```